Need help in Pivot table or Formatting the data
I have a scenario where I have the list of promotions by each job level by Month. In December, the promotion receivership % is 6.6% and in June 2.5% however when I include both I was expecting 9.1%. However Pivot is giving me 4.6%. I know the reason, its because of the denominator is different for each month. I have pasted pivots screen print below. I need a help to understand how to modify the Pivot or modify my original data to get 9.1% overall and 6.6%/2.5% when I select the respective months.
I tried to rearrange the data but its not helping. I am looking for overall year 9.1% and Dec-6.6% and June 2.5%
Update: 15th July
Sorry, for some reason the image did not post so I am adding file now.

If you attached an image it didn't stay so please try again.

So, you are looking to cumulate the Promotions, but not the Headcount?  (i.e. if you had 1000 staff in December, with 66 promotions; and you had 1000 staff in June, with 25 promotions; then you want to calculate that there were 91 promotions across 1000 staff, not that there were 91 promotions across 2000 staff?)

I'm wondering whether you could add a separate row for combined results by adding a formula based on slicers. Here's a good tutorial: Using slicers with formulas (2022 update) | Excel Off The Grid - YouTube

By math, you cannot sum, average the percentage value. 4.6% is correct when both the months are considered

@PunithGubbi I doubt that the company has 100% turnover between December and June; so, the "Full Year" table will be double-counting people who were employed in both months.  However, that requires either extending the data tables (not shown), or using non-pivot tables with a Count on Unique UserIDs.  So, I would expect the "true" number to be higher than 4.6%… but, yes, not a full 9.1%.  If we only had people leaving, and no new hires in that time, then it's 4600 of 51600, which is 8.9% as the maximum possible percentage.

Simplifying down slightly (by removing the Level), consider the following table of users:



[A] User
[B] Month
[C] Promoted?




A
Dec 2023
TRUE


B
Dec 2023
TRUE


C
Dec 2023
TRUE


D
Dec 2023
FALSE


E
Dec 2023
FALSE


A
Jun 2024
FALSE


C
Jun 2024
FALSE


D
Jun 2024
TRUE


F
Jun 2024
TRUE



Now, to work things out for December or June, you just do a COUNTIF to get the number of Users, and a COUNTIFS to get the number of promotions, then you divide one by t'other:



[F] Month
[G] Users
[H] Promotion
[I] Received




2023-12-01
=COUNTIF($B:$B,F2)
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,F2,$C:$C,TRUE)
=H2/G2


2024-06-01
=COUNTIF($B:$B,F3)
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,F3,$C:$C,TRUE)
=H3/G3






[F] Month
[G] Users
[H] Promotion
[I] Received




Dec 2023
5
3
60%


Jun 2024
4
2
50%



However, for the total, it is more complicated:  Users A, C, and D were present in both months.  Users B and E were present in December, but had left by June.  And User F joined at some point after December.
This means that, rather than a total of 9 users (with 5 promotions, for 55.56% received), we have a total of 6 unique users (in this example, still with 5 promotions).  So, we need to count (or, rather COUNTA) the UNIQUE users, sometimes after FILTERing for a promotion:



[F] Month
[G] Users
[H] Promotion
[I] Received




Total
=COUNTA(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$10))
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$10,$C$2:$C$10)))
=H4/G4






[F] Month
[G] Users
[H] Promotion
[I] Received




Total
6
5
83.33%




As can (hopefully) be seen, this means that your data cannot be properly compared in this way from its aggregated form — and that a unique reference for each user that remains static between months is required:  Depending on what your turnover is, the final percentage could be anywhere from 4.6% (if everyone left after December, and was replaced before June) to 8.9% (if people left after December, but no one new joined)
(Actually, there's a third extreme to consider: if 50400 people left the company after December, all 1200 who stayed had been promoted, then 47400 joined the company before June, but only  the 1200 who had received promotions in December and stayed were promoted in June, then only 3400 people received promotions — albeit 1200 of them were promoted twice — out of 99000 unique employees, which gives a receivership of 3.43%)

Thanks for your time. I like your answer however companies does not want to show in that way. Dec 6.6% + June 2.5% = Full year 9.1%. This has to be shown in the pivot or any other table format with slicers.

@AnilKumar Unfortunately — put simply — what they are asking for is worthless trash.  It's like saying "we made 60% profit on $1 millon in January, and 40% profit on $3 million in February, so we made 100% profit on $4 million in the first two months of the year!", and then basing their Executive Bonuses on making  $4 million in profit. No, you made $600k profit in January, and $1.2m profit in February, for a total of $1.8m profit on $4m, which is 45% profit in the first two months.

(To further demonstrate: using the sample-data I provided, the method your company wants to use would mean claiming that 110% (60%+50%) of the workforce received promotions!  Depending on what this data is being used for — e.g. audits, etc — you may want to head over to [workplace.se], and ask something like "What to do if my company is asking me to commit fraud?")
